# freeze first column of html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to freeze the first column of my html table.  after a few attempts i manage to freeze it but somehow when i scroll the table horizontally the columns at the left seems like overlapped with the first column.  i couldn't find a way to fix it.  can you please help?  you can use this [codepen](https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ) to test it out.

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
thead {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
thead th:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width:200px;
}
tbody {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    max-height: 307px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
   min-width:200px;
}
table th, table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) {
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

Comment: the original of the css and js code above are come from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071085/freeze-first-row-and-first-column-of-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `background-color` for first column?

```
table th:first-child,
table td:first-child {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: it somehow fix my problem :)

Comment: sorry for stupid question, does the js above has dependency on the jquery?  i try to remove jquery and it doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: somehow it didn't work as expected in my dash-plotly apps.  https://community.plot.ly/t/freeze-first-column-in-html-table/12230

Answer (score 0):

There some problem when you fixed column min-width I have fixed that by using

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]