# javascript work in codepen but not work for dynamically object created in my plotly-dash app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plotly-dash

the javascript below are tested in codepen but when it is not working in my webpage.  the function supposed to freeze the first column of my table, the header remain static when I scroll my table to the left. after some discussion in the comments below it could be due to the html table is dynamically created, I am looking for help to convert the js below to handle this case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main-table tbody').scroll(function(e) {
    $('.main-table thead').css("left", -$(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('.main-table thead tr th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
    $('.main-table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $(".main-table tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
  });
});
```

a few attempts to make it work for dynamically created table but still not working.  can someone help to point out what i did wrong here:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.main-table tbody', function(){
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('thead tr th:first-child').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
    $('tbody tr td:first-child').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-2);
});
```

Comment: this is my codepen pointer: https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/bjaEKJ

Comment: look at console(F12) and see if you get any error

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: **it is not working in my webpage** explain it. Did you find any error in console log? Any screen freezing? anything else?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working? check if you CSS has overflow-y: hidden; if it is a scroll problem.

Comment: @user466130 you use jquery do you add jquery link in your `head` tag::https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp

Comment: the js is suppose to able to freeze the first column of the table but it is not.  the tbody is move along when i scroll to the left while header remain static.  i dun see any error when i press F12.  i am newbie in the web development, not quite familiar how to debug using F12

Comment: Make sure the developer console is open (usually via F12), then reload your page. Anything reported in red is something to worry about. Do you see anything?

Comment: i don't see error using F12 when i refresh my page with F5

Comment: Try scrolling the table, do you see any errors then?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: i use chrome.  this page is targeted to none-IE browser.

Comment: is it on a localhost or can we see it live?

Comment: it is on a localhost. sorry about that.

Comment: Remove the js, what happens?

Comment: i also open a ticket in plotly community, just afraid it is something in the dash module causing the problem.  https://community.plot.ly/t/freeze-first-column-in-html-table/12230

Comment: currently the page is work like without the js. =.="

Comment: Is it possible the table is built dynamically from asynchronously retrieved data or simply at a later time? Ie, when the page initially loads, there is no `<table class="main-table">`. Change your JS to `jQuery(function($) { alert($('.main-table tbody').length) })`. What number do you see alerted?

Comment: I did not understand your answer dear user, from what I see the css is doing the job that you need and not the js, right?

Comment: Phil, maybe you are right...i get 0 in the popup window.  do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Torjescu Sergiu, to explain what i did here you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071085/freeze-first-row-and-first-column-of-table

Comment: @Phil my second code in the same js file also applied to an object which is dynamically created